# how to use fread on malloc strings

Tags: c, malloc, fwrite, fread

Can someone help me understand why it's entering unknown chars to temp?
I'm trying to binary copy one file to the other one.
Thanks a head!

```
 int size=0;
 fseek(srcFiles,0, SEEK_END);
 size = ftell(srcFiles);
 printf("%d", size);
 char* temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(size+1));
 fread(temp, sizeof(char), size , srcFiles);
 printf("%s", temp);
 fwrite(temp, sizeof(char), size , dstFiles)
```

Comment: have u checked that all the files are opened? Did you step through with a debugger? You should look at fread return value to see how much it has read. fread wont null terminate the bytes so printf will run off the end

Comment: In `printf("%s", temp);` how do you know there is only one `'\0'` in the file? You mentioned "binary". And after you reserve one extra byte with `malloc` you don't even set that supposed one byte to `'\0'`!

Comment: `printf("%s", temp);` is a red herring. You are confusing binary data with text data. What matters is if the target file is the same as the source file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is that you do not seek back to the start of the file after seeking to the end (to determine the file size using `ftell`).

As already has been said, you also need to add a null terminator if you use `printf` in this way.

Comment: Nice answer :D it did work for me 100%